# Reset page counter in Rmarkdown when knitting to Word document

Tags: r-markdown

I am writing a manuscript with a supplement in the same rmarkdown file, knitting to Word. How can I reset the page counter such that the first page of the supplement is page 1? I've tried `\setcounter{page}{0}`, but it doesn't seem to work when the output is a Word document.

My header, in case it helps:

```
---
title: 'Optimal portfolios of blood safety interventions: test, defer or modify?'
author: 
csl: american-medical-association-brackets.csl
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: word-style-reference-manuscript.docx
  pdf_document: default
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{amsfonts} 
bibliography: Blood_safety_portfolio.bib
---
```